# Temporarily remove one variable of environment PATH in Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, path, environment-variables, mingw

I build my project with CMake.

I want to generate "MinGW Makefiles",
but CMake throws me this error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeMinGWFindMake.cmake:12 (message):
  sh.exe was found in your PATH, here:

  C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe

  For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path.

  Run cmake from a shell that does not have sh.exe in your PATH.

  If you want to use a UNIX shell, then use MSYS Makefiles.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

It seems that only this needs to be deleted:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

in my environment variable `Path`.

So I want to know how to do this in Windows CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this in your command line environment before running `cmake`:

```
set PATH=%PATH:C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;=%
```

This will remove the specific path (`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;`) from your `PATH` string variable, and reassigns `PATH`, using string [substitution](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Remove).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also want to know how linux do. Would you tell me?

Comment: Please see the answers to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108873/removing-a-directory-from-path) for Linux cases.